# How Can I Make My Powershell Get-WMIObject Script Faster Cycling Through Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, powershell

I am working on a script which checks a server for ping and then checks all SQL Server Services status and stores this in a table. It also caters for SQL Instances. However I have to check across 70 servers and it takes over a minute to run. I looked into the AsJob parameter and when I added this to all my "Get_WMIObject xxService" Commands it started returning the wrong information for each Service. i.e it started returning "running" status for all so I suspect it was just repeating the previous data capture. Although it did run in just 20 seconds. Can someone take a look below and advise where I am going wrong or what I can do to make the retrieval of the server service information asynchronous?

I thought it might be better the to store the Service status for all servers in a hashtable and update the SQL DataTable in one go but its proving quite complicated. I feel my code needs a complete rethink in order to run asynchronously but I am trying to avoid this!

Thanks in advance

```
<#
Tests all Servers for Ping and SQL Server Service Status
#>

# Return the Ping Status
Function GetStatusCode 
{  
    Param([int] $StatusCode)   
    switch($StatusCode) 
    { 
        0         {"Success"} 
        11001   {"Buffer Too Small"} 
        11002   {"Destination Net Unreachable"} 
        11003   {"Destination Host Unreachable"} 
        11004   {"Destination Protocol Unreachable"} 
        11005   {"Destination Port Unreachable"} 
        11006   {"No Resources"} 
        11007   {"Bad Option"} 
        11008   {"Hardware Error"} 
        11009   {"Packet Too Big"} 
        11010   {"Request Timed Out"} 
        11011   {"Bad Request"} 
        11012   {"Bad Route"} 
        11013   {"TimeToLive Expired Transit"} 
        11014   {"TimeToLive Expired Reassembly"} 
        11015   {"Parameter Problem"} 
        11016   {"Source Quench"} 
        11017   {"Option Too Big"} 
        11018   {"Bad Destination"} 
        11032   {"Negotiating IPSEC"} 
        11050   {"General Failure"} 
        default {"Failed"} 
    } 
} 

# Format the Server Up-time
Function GetUpTime 
{ 
    param([string] $LastBootTime) 
    $Uptime = (Get-Date) - [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($LastBootTime) 
    "Days: $($Uptime.Days); Hours: $($Uptime.Hours); Minutes: $($Uptime.Minutes); Seconds: $($Uptime.Seconds)"  
} 

#Main Body
# Populate Table MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=MyServer; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=SSPI")
$conn.Open()

$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText ="DELETE FROM MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest
INSERT INTO MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest (ServerName, InstanceName)
SELECT ServerName, InstanceName FROM MyDB.dbo.tbl_servers
WHERE ServerCategory <> 'DECOMMED'"
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd2 = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest"
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter #($cmd2)
$da.SelectCommand = $cmd2
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$da.Fill($dt) | Out-Null

# Cycle through Server and Instances and retrieve information
Foreach($row in $dt.rows) 
{ 
    $ServerName = $row.ServerName
    $InstanceName = $row.InstanceName

    $pingStatus = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from win32_PingStatus where Address='$ServerName'" 

    $Uptime = $null 
    $SQLServerStatus = $null 
    $SQLAgentStatus = $null 

    # Enter the Loop if a Server is Pingable
    if($pingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0) 
    { 
        # Trap needed for server where Access is Denied causes the SQL Job to fail
        trap {continue}
        $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ServerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable wmiResults
        $Uptime = GetUptime( $OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime ) 

        if ($wmiResults -ne $null)
          {
            $tmperr = "Uptime Info Could Not be Obtained"
            $Uptime = $null
          }
        else
          {
            $tmperr = ""

            filter SvcFilter {
                if ($_.StartMode -eq "Disabled") {$_.StartMode }
                else {$_.State}
                }

            $props="Name","StartMode","State"

            if ($InstanceName -eq 'DEFAULT') 
                {
                    $SQLServerStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -filter "name='MSSQLSERVER'" -computer $ServerName | SvcFilter
                    $SQLAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -filter "name='SQLSERVERAGENT'" -computer $ServerName | SvcFilter
                    $RSAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -filter "name='ReportServer'" -computer $ServerName | SvcFilter
                }
                else
                {
                    $NamedInstanceSQLService = "MSSQL$" + $InstanceName
                    $NamedInstanceAgentService = "SQLAgent$" + $InstanceName
                    $NamedInstanceRSService = "ReportServer$" + $InstanceName
                    $SQLServerStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -computer $ServerName | where {$_.name -eq $NamedInstanceSQLService} | SvcFilter
                    $SQLAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -computer $ServerName | where {$_.name -eq $NamedInstanceAgentService} | SvcFilter
                    $RSAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -computer $ServerName | where {$_.name -eq $NamedInstanceRSService} | SvcFilter
                }

            $ASAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -filter "name='MSSQLServerOLAPService'" -computer $ServerName | SvcFilter

          }
    } 

    $IPAddress = $pingStatus.IPV4Address
    $PingTest = GetStatusCode( $pingStatus.StatusCode ) 
    $ErrMSG = $tmperr

    # Update Table MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest with all retreived information 
    $updateRow = $dt.Select("ServerName = '$ServerName' AND InstanceName = '$InstanceName'")
    $updateRow[0].IPAddress = $IPAddress
    $updateRow[0].PingTest = $PingTest
    $updateRow[0].ErrMSG = $ErrMSG
    $updateRow[0].Uptime = $Uptime
    $updateRow[0].SQLServerStatus = $SQLServerStatus
    $updateRow[0].SQLAgentStatus = $SQLAgentStatus   
    $updateRow[0].RSAgentStatus = $RSAgentStatus 
    $updateRow[0].ASAgentStatus = $ASAgentStatus 

    $cmdUpd = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmdUpd.CommandText = "UPDATE MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest
    SET IPAddress = @IPAddress, PingTest = @PingTest, ErrMSG = @ErrMSG, Uptime = @Uptime, SQLServerStatus = @SQLServerStatus, SQLAgentStatus = @SQLAgentStatus, RSAgentStatus = @RSAgentStatus, ASAgentStatus = @ASAgentStatus
    WHERE ServerName = @ServerName AND InstanceName = @InstanceName"

    # Add parameters to pass values to the UPDATE statement
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@ServerName", "nvarchar", 50, "ServerName") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@ServerName"].SourceVersion = "Original"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@InstanceName", "nvarchar", 50, "InstanceName") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@InstanceName"].SourceVersion = "Original"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@IPAddress", "nvarchar", 50, "IPAddress") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@IPAddress"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@PingTest", "nvarchar", 50, "PingTest") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@PingTest"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@ErrMSG", "nvarchar", 50, "ErrMSG") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@ErrMSG"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@Uptime", "nvarchar", 50, "Uptime") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@Uptime"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@SQLServerStatus", "nvarchar", 50, "SQLServerStatus") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@SQLServerStatus"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@SQLAgentStatus", "nvarchar", 50, "SQLAgentStatus") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@SQLAgentStatus"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@RSAgentStatus", "nvarchar", 50, "RSAgentStatus") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@RSAgentStatus"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@ASAgentStatus", "nvarchar", 50, "ASAgentStatus") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@ASAgentStatus"].SourceVersion = "Current"

    # Set the UpdateCommand property
    $da.UpdateCommand = $cmdUpd

    # Update the database
    $RowsUpdated = $da.Update($dt)


} 

$conn.Close()
```

I tried to add the -AsJob Parameter to each of the Get-WMIObject lines

i.e

```
$SQLServerStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -computer $ServerName | where {$_.name -eq $NamedInstanceSQLService} -AsJob | SvcFilter
```

but I didnt use Receive-Job anywhere in the code. What I noticed it that every variable returns a "Running" status even if it is "Stopped" or "disabled". So I am guessing that the result of the Job is not being captured properly and it is in fact returning the output of a previous Get-WMIObject call (most of which will be of "Running" status).

Answer (score 0):

`get-wmiobject` has an `-asjob` parameter, but `where-object` doesn't.

Also, when you use -asjob, the return value is a "job object" rather than the objects that would be returned by, for example, the get-wmiobject call.

You use the `receive-job` cmdlet to get the actual objects back from each job once it is complete on the remote server (and you can use `wait-job` and `get-job` to help to know when it is done).

I would recommend doing a `get-help about_Remote_Jobs` to get some background on how to structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

If your get-wmiObject [wants](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/645165/add-timeout-parameter-to-get-wmiobject) a [shorter timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15054702/1751302) , the [get-wmiCustom function](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7bae3d39-c6c3-4a8a-8c98-1b8851bd2cbe) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with a re-write using Start-Job and its reduced from 80 seconds to 20 seconds. I would appreciate it if anyone has any further suggestions with regards to how to making it even more efficient. I am thinking about retrieving all the WMIObjects in one go rather than one by one? Can anyone suggest how?

```
#Main Body
# Populate Table MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=MyServer; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=SSPI")
$conn.Open()

$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText ="DELETE FROM MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest
INSERT INTO MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest (ServerName, InstanceName)
SELECT ServerName, InstanceName FROM MyDB.dbo.tbl_servers
WHERE ServerCategory <> 'DECOMMED'"
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd2 = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest"
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter #($cmd2)
$da.SelectCommand = $cmd2
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$da.Fill($dt) | Out-Null

# Create list
$serverlist = @()

$sb = {
    param ([string] $ServerName, [string] $InstanceName)

    # Return the Ping Status
    Function GetStatusCode 
    {  
        Param([int] $StatusCode)   
        switch($StatusCode) 
        { 
            0         {"Success"} 
            11001   {"Buffer Too Small"} 
            11002   {"Destination Net Unreachable"} 
            11003   {"Destination Host Unreachable"} 
            11004   {"Destination Protocol Unreachable"} 
            11005   {"Destination Port Unreachable"} 
            11006   {"No Resources"} 
            11007   {"Bad Option"} 
            11008   {"Hardware Error"} 
            11009   {"Packet Too Big"} 
            11010   {"Request Timed Out"} 
            11011   {"Bad Request"} 
            11012   {"Bad Route"} 
            11013   {"TimeToLive Expired Transit"} 
            11014   {"TimeToLive Expired Reassembly"} 
            11015   {"Parameter Problem"} 
            11016   {"Source Quench"} 
            11017   {"Option Too Big"} 
            11018   {"Bad Destination"} 
            11032   {"Negotiating IPSEC"} 
            11050   {"General Failure"} 
            default {"Failed"} 
        } 
    }

    # Format the Server Up-time
    Function GetUpTime 
    { 
        param([string] $LastBootTime) 
        $Uptime = (Get-Date) - [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($LastBootTime) 
        "Days: $($Uptime.Days); Hours: $($Uptime.Hours); Minutes: $($Uptime.Minutes); Seconds: $($Uptime.Seconds)"  
    } 

    try {

        # Fetch IP
        $pingStatus = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from win32_PingStatus where Address='$ServerName'"

        $Uptime = $null 
        $SQLServerStatus = $null 
        $SQLAgentStatus = $null 

        # Enter the Loop if a Server is Pingable
        if($pingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0) 
        { 
            # Trap needed for server where Access is Denied causes the SQL Job to fail
            trap {continue}
            $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ServerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable wmiResults
            $Uptime = GetUptime( $OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime ) 

            if ($wmiResults -ne $null)
              {
                $tmperr = "Uptime Info Could Not be Obtained"
                $Uptime = $null
              }
            else
              {
                $tmperr = ""

                filter SvcFilter {
                    if ($_.StartMode -eq "Disabled") {$_.StartMode }
                    else {$_.State}
                    }

                $props="Name","StartMode","State"

                if ($InstanceName -eq 'DEFAULT') 
                    {
                        #Write-Host $ServerName + '\' + $InstanceName 
                        $SQLServerStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -filter "name='MSSQLSERVER'" -computer $ServerName | SvcFilter
                        #Write-Host $SQLServerStatus
                        $SQLAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -filter "name='SQLSERVERAGENT'" -computer $ServerName | SvcFilter
                        #Write-Host $SQLAgentStatus
                        $RSAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -filter "name='ReportServer'" -computer $ServerName | SvcFilter
                        #Write-Host $RSAgentStatus
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        #Write-Host $ServerName + '\' + $InstanceName 
                        $NamedInstanceSQLService = "MSSQL$" + $InstanceName
                        $NamedInstanceAgentService = "SQLAgent$" + $InstanceName
                        $NamedInstanceRSService = "ReportServer$" + $InstanceName
                        $SQLServerStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -computer $ServerName | where {$_.name -eq $NamedInstanceSQLService} | SvcFilter
                        $SQLAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -computer $ServerName | where {$_.name -eq $NamedInstanceAgentService} | SvcFilter
                        $RSAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -computer $ServerName | where {$_.name -eq $NamedInstanceRSService} | SvcFilter
                    }

                $ASAgentStatus = Get-WMIObject win32_service -property $props -filter "name='MSSQLServerOLAPService'" -computer $ServerName | SvcFilter

              }
        } 

        $IPAddress = $pingStatus.IPV4Address
        $PingTest = GetStatusCode( $pingStatus.StatusCode ) 
        $ErrMSG = $tmperr

        # Save info about server
        $serverInfo = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        ServerName = $ServerName
        InstanceName = $InstanceName
        IPAddress = $IPAddress
        PingTest = $PingTest
        ErrMSG = $ErrMSG
        Uptime = $Uptime
        SQLServerStatus = $SQLServerStatus
        SQLAgentStatus = $SQLAgentStatus   
        RSAgentStatus = $RSAgentStatus 
        ASAgentStatus = $ASAgentStatus 

        }
        return $serverInfo
    } catch {
        throw 'Failed to process server named {0}. The error was "{1}".' -f $ServerName, $_
    }
}

# Loop servers
$max = 5
$jobs = @()
foreach($row in $dt.rows) {
    #$InstanceName = "DEFAULT"
    $server = $row.ServerName
    $InstanceName = $row.InstanceName
    $jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList @($server, $InstanceName) 
    $running = @($jobs | ? {$_.State -eq 'Running'})

    # Throttle jobs.
    while ($running.Count -ge $max) {
        $finished = Wait-Job -Job $jobs -Any
        $running = @($jobs | ? {$_.State -eq 'Running'})
    }
}

# Wait for remaining.
Wait-Job -Job $jobs > $null

# Check for failed jobs.
$failed = @($jobs | ? {$_.State -eq 'Failed'})
if ($failed.Count -gt 0) {
    $failed | % {
        $_.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo.Reason.Message
    }
}

# Collect job data.
$jobs | % {
    $serverlist += $_ | Receive-Job | Select-Object ServerName,InstanceName,IPAddress,PingTest,ErrMSG,Uptime,SQLServerStatus,SQLAgentStatus,RSAgentStatus,ASAgentStatus
}

#$serverlist

Foreach($row in $serverlist) 
{ 
    $ServerName = $row.ServerName
    $InstanceName = $row.InstanceName

    #$dt.Select("ServerName = '$ServerName' AND InstanceName = '$InstanceName'")

    $IPAddress = $row.IPAddress
    $PingTest = $row.PingTest
    $ErrMSG = $row.ErrMSG
    $Uptime = $row.Uptime
    $SQLServerStatus = $row.SQLServerStatus
    $SQLAgentStatus = $row.SQLAgentStatus   
    $RSAgentStatus = $row.RSAgentStatus 
    $ASAgentStatus = $row.ASAgentStatus 


   # Write-Host $ServerName
   # Write-Host $InstanceName

    $updateRow = $dt.Select("ServerName = '$ServerName' AND InstanceName = '$InstanceName'")
    $updateRow[0].IPAddress = $IPAddress
    $updateRow[0].PingTest = $PingTest
    $updateRow[0].ErrMSG = $ErrMSG
    $updateRow[0].Uptime = $Uptime
    $updateRow[0].SQLServerStatus = $SQLServerStatus
    $updateRow[0].SQLAgentStatus = $SQLAgentStatus   
    $updateRow[0].RSAgentStatus = $RSAgentStatus 
    $updateRow[0].ASAgentStatus = $ASAgentStatus 

    $cmdUpd = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmdUpd.CommandText = "UPDATE MyDB.dbo.tbl_ServerPingTest
    SET IPAddress = @IPAddress, PingTest = @PingTest, ErrMSG = @ErrMSG, Uptime = @Uptime, SQLServerStatus = @SQLServerStatus, SQLAgentStatus = @SQLAgentStatus, RSAgentStatus = @RSAgentStatus, ASAgentStatus = @ASAgentStatus
    WHERE ServerName = @ServerName AND InstanceName = @InstanceName"

    # Add parameters to pass values to the UPDATE statement
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@ServerName", "nvarchar", 50, "ServerName") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@ServerName"].SourceVersion = "Original"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@InstanceName", "nvarchar", 50, "InstanceName") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@InstanceName"].SourceVersion = "Original"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@IPAddress", "nvarchar", 50, "IPAddress") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@IPAddress"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@PingTest", "nvarchar", 50, "PingTest") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@PingTest"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@ErrMSG", "nvarchar", 50, "ErrMSG") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@ErrMSG"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@Uptime", "nvarchar", 50, "Uptime") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@Uptime"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@SQLServerStatus", "nvarchar", 50, "SQLServerStatus") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@SQLServerStatus"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@SQLAgentStatus", "nvarchar", 50, "SQLAgentStatus") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@SQLAgentStatus"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@RSAgentStatus", "nvarchar", 50, "RSAgentStatus") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@RSAgentStatus"].SourceVersion = "Current"
    $cmdUpd.Parameters.Add("@ASAgentStatus", "nvarchar", 50, "ASAgentStatus") | Out-Null
    $cmdUpd.Parameters["@ASAgentStatus"].SourceVersion = "Current"

    # Set the UpdateCommand property
    $da.UpdateCommand = $cmdUpd

    # Update the database
    $RowsUpdated = $da.Update($dt)

}

$conn.Close()
```